# How to Rewrite engine for form submission?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

How to get form elements in URL while using ht access file
i am using ht access file which consist of these lines

```
Rewrite Engine On  
Rewrite for index.php  
Rewrite Rule ^index/([0-9 a-z A-Z]+) index.php?u=$1 [NC,L]
```

i want to submit a form and then want url in this way :          website/index.php/123

Comment: Firstly, that is not a valid `.htaccess` file.

Comment: RewriteEngine On  
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^index/([-_a-zA-Z0-9]+) index.php?u=$1
its working

Comment: okay please tell me how to get form data in URL